# Logic of a SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

My Query does not work logically. I am trying to get a list of students who studied any AutoCAD course who has not studied any Revit Course. My Query is structured like this:

```
Select * From StudentData 
Where (CourseName LIKE 'AutoCAD%') 
AND NOT EXISTS (Select * From StudentData Where (CourseName LIKE 'Revit%'));
```

Doing the inverse of the EXISTS does give me a list of who studied both AutoCAD + Revit, but the NOT does not return any value.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
    * 
From 
    StudentData sd
Where 
    (
      CourseName LIKE 'AutoCAD%'
    ) 
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
        Select 
            * 
        From 
            StudentData sd2 
        Where 
            sd2.CourseName LIKE 'Revit%' 
        AND sd.StudentName = sd2.StudentName
    )
```

You missed out the id comparison from both the tables. Since there will at least 1 student with 'Revit%' course, `NOT EXISTS` condition will always fail for all student.

*****Demo(with sample data)*****

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a0c05/2

Comment: This Query Returns no records. ID is primary key.

Comment: I have confirmed that the sample data has students where students have studied autocad but not revit.

Comment: can you share create table syntax and few sample insert values?

Comment: I have added sqlfiddle link in my answer with sample data. Please check.

Comment: updated query and demo link for the sample data provided. Since id is different even for same user, you have to compare using studentName

Comment: Hi Rahul. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT IN`, instead. Try:

```
  SELECT *
FROM StudentData
WHERE (CourseName LIKE 'AutoCAD%')
    AND CourseName NOT IN (
        SELECT CourseName
        FROM StudentData
        WHERE (CourseName LIKE 'Revit%')
        )
```

Comment: This query isn't making much sense, there is no obvious link from the parent query to the correlated sub-query

Comment: Also, this query will test both conditions on same row, hence all the `AutoCAD%` courses will be returned irrespective of student with other courses.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below one

```
Select * From StudentData sd1
Where CourseName LIKE 'AutoCAD%'
AND NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM From StudentData sd2 WHERE sd1.Id = sd2.Id and CourseName LIKE 'Revit%')
```